# Implement method from view in caller class

Tags: android, inheritance, android-view

I have the following class which extends View :

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {
...
public void methodImplementedHere () { int a=1; }
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            methodImplementedHere ();
            methodImplementedInActivity();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and the Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MyCustomView customView;
....
methodImplementedInActivity () {int b=4}
}
```

Can I implement the method in the activity, but call it inside the view class?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a instance of MyCustomView and then call method.

```
MyCustomView mcv = new MyCustomView();

mcv.methodImplementedHere();
```

Or you can create new class which will extends MyCustomView and override method.

```
public class SecondCustomView extends MyCustomView {
    public SecondCustomView(param...) {
    super(param...)
  }
  @Override
  public void methodImplementedHere() { int a = 4 }
}
```

and call it in activity

```
SecondCustomView scv = new SecondCustomView(param...) 
scv.methodImplementedHere(); // int a = 4;
```